# Same public key with new assembly

Tags: .net, assemblies, public-key

Is it possible to generate the same public key for a new assembly as a previous one occupied? We have a collection of controls that need to be migrated to Visual Studio 2010, and the upgrade process from 2008 to 2010 keeps on breaking, so was thinking of re-writing the assemblies, but we need to retain the public key tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible (use the same key.snk during build). Is it a good idea? As far as I understand it, you should only share the same public key if you feel comfortable with both assemblies sharing the same security context.